# Is there a way to add input text to the autocomplete dropdown without hitting Enter?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web UI that has a form which users can either fill out themselves, or load data into and then edit. They want certain fields to use the autocomplete option, and so to start I've added this to one field:

```
<form type="submit" autocomplete="on">
    <input type="text" class="form-cmd" id="command"
            name="command" ng-model="fields.command" />
</form>
```

This sort of works, but not the way I need it to. Regardless of whether the user types it in or loads the info into the field, they have to hit Enter or else the text doesn't get included in the autocomplete list. The problem is that there's currently no requirement to use the Enter key (and in practice nobody does). Once the form is filled out, a button (Add Entry) is clicked that takes all the info in 'fields' (which includes all the info from the form, fields.command, fields.name, etc) and then makes a REST call using that data as args.

I've been toying around with trying to just trigger an 'Enter' keypress in that field programatically behind the scenes in the Command text field when the Add Entry button is clicked, but so far I haven't had any luck and I'm wondering if I'm not just missing something simple here. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I wonder if programmatically triggering a form submission (then intercepting and overriding the submission) would also add the text to the autocomplete dictionary

Comment: *"in practice nobody does"* ... not so sure about that part. Lots of people navigate with keyboard. Quicker and easier to do form submits hitting enter right as you type or select from a dropdown. Can't always assume that your use habits match all others

Comment: Seems like a security issue if you could do it. I could any fake value to it. (but I do see why you would want to)

Comment: @charlietfl That's fair - maybe a better way to put it is 'I can't guarantee that all (or any) of them will'. I'm just trying to avoid it as a requirement.